# Infer nesting generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

To demonstrate the problem I've prepared this code:

```cs
public interface IParser<T>
{
    bool TryParse(string s, out T result);
}

public sealed class TimeSpanParser : IParser<TimeSpan>
{
    public bool TryParse(string s, out TimeSpan result)
    {
        result = TimeSpan.Zero;
        return true;
    }
}

public static class ParserService
{
    public static T Parse<TParser, T>(string s)
        where TParser : IParser<T>, new()
    {
        var parser = new TParser();
        parser.TryParse(s, out var result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The way to call `ParserService.Parse` is

```cs
var r = ParserService.Parse<TimeSpanParser, TimeSpan>("");
```

As you can see I need to specify `TimeSpan` type argument. But definition of the `Parse` method is

```cs
public static T Parse<TParser, T>(string s)
    where TParser : IParser<T>, new()
```

So in my opinion the compiler can infer `T` automatically by `TParser`. When I pass `TimeSpanParser` as type argument it's known that `TimeSpanParser` is `IParser<TimeSpan>` so `T` is `TimeSpan`. Is it possible to not specify `T`?

Like this

```cs
var r = ParserService.Parse<TimeSpanParser>("");
```

Comment: The `ParserService` class is essentially pointless here, why even have it in the first place?

Comment: I just show simplified code. In reality `ParserService.Parse` will do some complex work. I don't want to repeat it everywhere. The question about C#, please, don't think about architecture of this sample :)

Comment: Well with a better architecture, there is no worry about generic inference. C# does not allow you to specify partial generics, you infer all types or none.